# ida pro issue debugging issues with ntdll

Tags: ida, malware

I am using IDA pro to follow along a youtube video of RE from OALabs. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdNQhfgoQoU&t=1575s

I am facing a problem when i try to put a break point on functions in ntdll, when i double click c:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll in the modules windows I get warning saying "Module c:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll has no names". When i right click on c:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll in the modules window and select load debug symbols, it downloads something but I am still not able to see the functions i would like to put break point on like NtResumeThread.

Appreciate any assistance or suggestions. Pic[image] attached for reference.[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better of at Hex Rays support (https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/)

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Wait, what's your problem here? From user mode the `Zw*` and `Nt*` functions are _literally_ identical. Just their names differ, entry points to the kernel _will be_ identical. And typically they are exported in pairs, so that's somewhat odd in your case. But still placing a bpx on `ZwResumeThread` should do the job. Also, your question lacks details such as what exact environment you were running in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the breakpoint on `ZwResumeThread` (also shown in your screenshot). From user mode the only difference between `NtResumeThread` and `ZwResumeThread` is the name prefix. In kernel mode these functions (of `ntoskrnl.exe` instead of `ntdll.dll`) have implementation differences indeed.

You may want to brush up on Windows internals a bit. [This article by Geoff Chappell](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/ntdll/api/native.htm) may help.